# How to include multiple rendered JSP into response to AJAX?

Tags: java, ajax, jsp

I need to send ajax request to java back-end and to response (from java back-end) with two html-blocks as answer. I want to generate those two html-blocks using two different JSPs. I do this as following:

```
req.setAttribute(...);
...
resp.setContentType("text/html");
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("one.jsp");
dispatcher.include(req, resp);
dispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("two.jsp");
dispatcher.include(req, resp);
```

And it works. But on the front-end I receive an answer like one solid html code (rendered one.jsp + rendered two.jsp). But I need to receive it as two separate html blocks to put each block to it's own .
What is the proper way to do this?

Ajax code:

```
    function addNew() {
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "myUrl",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#divNameOne").html(<one part of data>);
                $("#divNameTwo").html(<second part of data>);
            },
            error:function() {
                alert("fail");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you share js code block ? It seems you need to seperate html blocks in your js. If you are okay with single ajax request.

Comment: I've updated question with ajax code. So the only way is to parse code in Java Script?

Comment: are you loading an html fragment and inserting it into an existing div?What is the purpose of two html block? Can you give more context?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake when editing question. Now I updated it one more time. I need to put every html block to it's own div - that is the purpose.

Comment: do you have unique ids or classes in your jsps? , so you will be able to select  certain block from your data.

Comment: Yes, I have ids. For example I receive this string from java back-end: "<div id='div1'>...</div>  _new lines_ <div id='div2'>...</div>". What is the best way to separate this string into two parts (with div1 and div2)?

Answer (score 0):

In your success function ,

```
var reponseHtml = $(data); // or you can use $($.parseHtml(data));
$("#divNameOne").html(responseHtml.find("#div1").html());
$("#divNameTwo").html(responseHtml.find("#div2").html());
```

It might work.